# onclick function not using the else option

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a form which opens and closes and uses `style="display: block"` when clicked to open and `style="display: none"` when closed. I have used javascript to print to the console when each condition is met, however no matter what I try the if statement always remains `visible`.

When I try to `console.log` it returns the correct value of the current display option. Here is the code:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.request-quote-form').style.display)
```

When I run the function it always prints out `visible`. Any ideas? I have also tried this in jQuery and I'm receiving the same results.

```
document.querySelector('.js-request-quote-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('.request-quote-form').style.display);
    if (document.querySelector('.request-quote-form').style.display === "block") {
        console.log("visble");
    } else {
        console.log("nope");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], preferably in the form of a live demo using the [snippets feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Please try to use only two `=`, so that it says `.. .style.display == "block"`. I assume the returned value isn't the same datatype.

Comment: The issue is because you need to use the computed style: https://jsfiddle.net/h3gLfcvn/. See the duplicate for more information. Or better yet, use jQuery